# Newbie question: how can I send BNB to my ETH wallet?

Tags: metamask, binance

I'm trying to send some USDTs from my ETH main-net wallet to my BSC wallet. Binance bridge complains "insufficient funds" as I have no BNB in my ETH wallet. So I am trying to send some BNB to my ETH wallet. However, I have not found a way to do so. I have tried:

1. Withdraw directly from Binance to my ETH wallet. Binance doesn't allow me to do so.
2. Send BNB from my BSC wallet to ETH wallet. Binance bridge doesn't support sending BNB.

I'm stuck here, not sure how to send BNB to ETH wallet. Any suggestions?

**Update**: I confirmed that somehow in my Binance app I can only select BEP2 and BEP20 when withdrawing BNB. If I paste an ETH address in, it is automatically recognized as a BSC address.

[image]

Comment: Binance should allow you to do this. Did you reach out to their customer support team?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg somehow it doesn't allow me to ask questions in the support chat. The chat send button was grayed out. Also I added a picture into the original question showing that I can't select ERC20 when withdrawing BNB...

Comment: Can you show the exact error message you got? It is unlikely you will need BNB on the ETH side.

Comment: @Ismael what do you mean by exact error message? Do I need BNB on the ETH side to use the Binance bridge to send tokens to BSC? My goal is to send tokens to BSC.

Comment: Don't send BNB to an ETH address. What's the exact error you got when trying to use the bridge to send USDT from ETH address to a BSC address? Do you have ETH for the transaction fees?